# Concatenate and sum hours depending on condition in Excel / Calc

Tags: excel, concatenation, libreoffice-calc

I am having this example in Excel / Calc ([download here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BM-xo-5ui9uXgb-rHsew0kOEQvID3b4O/view?usp=sharing)):

[image]

I would like two things:

- to sum automatically TIME of category = MANAGEMENT (the same for MEETING)
- to concatenate (separated by ; ) description of category = MANAGEMENT (the same for MEETING). In case of MANAGEMENT it should be like this: `Task 1; Task 3; Tastk 5; Task 7; Task 8`.

How can I do these two options to have a matrix of two lines (Management and Meeting) and two columns (Times and Descriptions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the sum, you can use the [**SUMIF()**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060106.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3151957) or [**SUMPRODUCT()**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060107.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3163286) function

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$1000;O2;$E$2:$E$1000)
=SUMPRODUCT($A$2:$A$1000=O2;$E$2:$E$1000)
```

Just format the result as time and instead of 0.145833333333333 you get 03:30

The [**TEXTJOIN()**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/en-US/text/scalc/01/func_textjoin.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id581556228060864) function will help you to combine the required strings

```
{=TEXTJOIN(";";1;IF($A$2:$A$1000=O2;$B$2:$B$1000;""))}
```

Do not forget to enter it as an [**array formula**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060107.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3147273), finished entering **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks @JohnSUN, can you please share the ODS document?

Comment: I do not get to the point of your example @JohnSUN

Comment: OK, see [**here**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MkRqfmtalJyeRqQpo3W6Ps_DQIlZMikJ/view?usp=sharing)